# SharePoint Task ID Lookup

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, tasks, workflow-variable, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to auto-schedule task basis on Predecessors.
Tried creating a workflow that will help me with this but not been very successful.

For example-
Task2(ID2) with Predecessor(ID3) looks for TaskID(3) and saves DueDate(April 15) into a variable.
And then Updates Task2(ID2) StartDate with the same variable (April 15)

Thank you for your help

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While it might be possible using SharePoint 2013 style workflows, the workflow would be complicated and would have to make quite a few REST API web service calls to keep rerequesting the list data after each update. (each edit could change the order the tasks by date.)

Task scheduling can get very complex. Here's a few things to consider:

- The workflow would first need to find a starting point, probably the earliest dated task with no predecessors. (your drawing missed that Task 5 is the starting point.)
- It would have to deal with multiple tasks that have the same predecessor. Which one gets scheduled first?
- It would have to deal with a tree structure: Task 1 has dependent tasks 2, 3 and 4. Task 3 has dependent tasks 7, 14 and 28. Etc......
- Most projects have tasks that cannot be moved. (inspections, etc.) What does the workflow do with those?
- In most projects, it will need to deal with weekends. (Can your tasks be scheduled on weekends?)
- What will trigger the workflow? Do you want it to run on each update to a task or on demand?

This looks like a job for Microsoft Project... ;=)

Comment: Thank you for your response Mike. You are correct, I corrected my screenshot. First Task1, does not really have any dependency. I've been doing this on MS Project for long but for some reason its not happening on Sharepoint Task. Whats the point of having predecessors in Sharepoint is you can't auto-schedule a task?